# How to make WPF Application full-screen in cod?

Tags: c#, wpf

When I set the 'WindowState.Maximized' and 'WindowStyle.None' in XAML it works well but in code this doesn't works. TaskBar doesn`t disappear. Anyone knows where is the problem?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MWindow.WindowStyle != WindowStyle.None)
        { 
            MWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            MWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        }
        else
        {
            MWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
            MWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.WindowStyle != WindowStyle.None)
{
     this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
     this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
}
else
{
     this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
     this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
}
```

Comment: dear Oleg: whats the problem? i use this code and its ok

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by handling Activated event or overriding OnActivated method from App class, and huckup to ContentRendered event from your main window. You can also handle ContentRendered in the window itself, but note that with this approach it is not necessary to know who actually the main window is:

```
protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnActivated(e);


    Application.Current.MainWindow.ContentRendered += (s, a) =>
    {
        if (Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowStyle != WindowStyle.None)
        {
            Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
            Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taskbar will not dissapear until you also set the resolution:

```
MyWindow.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
MyWindow.Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
```